# Atualizar os Dados da Listagem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um pequeno problema, na imagem abaixo tenho uma listagem de clientes.
Existe um botão que abre um modal para edição, ele funciona normal, porém depois que edita o modal de fecha e preciso que atualize as informações da lista.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Editar(Cliente cliente)
    {
        cliente.Ativo = true;
        try
        {
            using (SistemaDBEntities db = new SistemaDBEntities())
            {
                db.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Sua Action Editar está sendo chamada?

Comment: Você está usando Ajax para a Modal?

Comment: Amigo se você usar o Modal gravando em Ajax a sua tela precisaria ser atualizada também com Ajax, com Angular ou JQuery (indicaria Angular) e ao receber desse método a resposta que gravou atualizaria os novos dados, pergunta-se como tu faz isso ?

Comment: @Cezar Eu gravo os dados com ajax, qual seria a codificação para atualizar via ajax?

Comment: Vc carrega os dados iniciais como?

Comment: Carrego assim: `db.Cliente.First(c => c.Codigo == id)`

Comment: Já resolvi....

Quando executo meu ajax eu coloquei o type como GET e funcionou.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter que executar um ajax de callback na conclusão da edição do modal para atualizar os dados da listagem, do contrário, somente usando redirect para a página de clientes (refresh).

**EDIT:** Eu não tinha percebido que era em asp, minha resolução se basearia em php com este back-end em HTML/javascript.